# How to Get All Components Except particular TCM ID by Using Criteria API

Tags: content-delivery, 2013-sp1, dd4t, query

I am trying to get all components based on the schema,  I have to ignore one particular tcm ID from the query. as i already have the component object in code.  i am unable to do  it.

This is my code now

```
AndCriteria totalCriteria = null;//this will be used for combining all kind of criteria 
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(myPublicationId);
ItemSchemaCriteria IsFVideSchema = new ItemSchemaCriteria(MySchemaID);
ItemTypeCriteria IsComponent = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);

//Here i want to include one more critera, so that ignore this TCM ID ("tcm:mypub-ItemId-16); 
//I want to get all the recent components by schema, it's working fine. But i already have one of component via component presentations //earlier, because of this reason i have to get top 4 components, but query including the one which i already have. 


TaxonomyKeywordCriteria taxonomyKeywordCriteria = new TaxonomyKeywordCriteria(catgoryId, keyWordId, false);
SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ItemLastPublishedDate, SortParameter.Descending);

totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(pubCriteria, IsFVideSchema );
totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(totalCriteria, IsComponent);
totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(totalCriteria, taxonomyKeywordCriteria);
query.Criteria = totalCriteria;
query.AddSorting(sortParameter);
PagingFilter Pagefilter = new PagingFilter(0, limit); //limit is 4 here
query.SetResultFilter(Pagefilter);
string[] ItemUris = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please can anyone help me ?, I just want to get the 4 components excluding this tcm ID. I have to ignore the component in Tridion Query, or else i will get the same component back again.  Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result you should use following two additional conditions:

1. LimitFilter - To limit no of components to 4
2. NotInCriteria - To exclude the component that you already have.

Let me know if you are still facing any issues.

Updated code will be something like:

```
AndCriteria totalCriteria = null;//this will be used for combining all kind of criteria 
PublicationCriteria pubCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(myPublicationId);
ItemSchemaCriteria IsFVideSchema = new ItemSchemaCriteria(MySchemaID);
ItemTypeCriteria IsComponent = new ItemTypeCriteria(16);

//Here i want to include one more critera, so that ignore this TCM ID ("tcm:mypub-ItemId-16); 
//I want to get all the recent components by schema, it's working fine. But i already have one of component via component presentations //earlier, because of this reason i have to get top 4 components, but query including the one which i already have. 
NotInCriteria notInCriteria = new NotInCriteria("<your component details>")

TaxonomyKeywordCriteria taxonomyKeywordCriteria = new TaxonomyKeywordCriteria(catgoryId, keyWordId, false);
SortParameter sortParameter = new SortParameter(SortParameter.ItemLastPublishedDate, SortParameter.Descending);

totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(pubCriteria, IsFVideSchema );
totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(totalCriteria, IsComponent);
totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(totalCriteria, taxonomyKeywordCriteria);
totalCriteria = new AndCriteria(totalCriteria, notInCriteria);

query.Criteria = totalCriteria;
query.AddSorting(sortParameter);
LimitFilter limitfilter = new LimitFilter(4); //limit is 4 here
query.SetResultFilter(limitfilter);
string[] ItemUris = query.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C670A0E9-7543-433B-899F-BE69802EA67F#docid=GUID-BC02E529-1316-42E7-BD24-B502CCD89ADA&filename=GUID-BC02E529-1316-42E7-BD24-B502CCD89ADA.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-BC02E529-1316-42E7-BD24-B502CCD89ADA

I used ItemReferenceCriteria with NotInCriteria it works fine.